# Calculating the Curl of a Velocity Field

Tags: calculus, vectors, vector-analysis, curl

The **curl** of a (velocity) field can be defined as:

$\nabla\times\vec{u}=(\frac{\partial\,\omega}{\partial\,y}-\frac{\partial\,v}{\partial\,z})\vec{i}+(\frac{\partial\,u}{\partial\,z}-\frac{\partial\,\omega}{\partial\,x})\vec{j}+(\frac{\partial\,v}{\partial\,x}-\frac{\partial\,u}{\partial\,y})\vec{k}$

The **question** is:
Does anyone know how such calculations work in practice?
If I have a (f.e.) velocity field with 3 x 10 velocity values - can I calculate the curl at the same 3 x 10 points? Since partial derivatives have to be calculated, wouldn't I always use 2 adjacent vectors? If so, how exactly is this done?

I hope that my question is understandable. If not, please let me know.

Comment: Are you trying to approximate $\nabla\times\vec{u}$ numerically from a set of data values?

Comment: @Paul yes, exactly

Comment: I assume this is 10 $\vec{u}=(u, v, w)$ values $(u_0, v_0, w_0)$ to $(u_9, v_9, w_9)$? I would guess $x, y$ and $z$ have the same increment h? Then you can put $\frac{\partial\,w_n}{\partial\,y}\approx \frac{w_{n+1}-w_n}{h}$ for $n=0...8$ and similarly for other derivatives. With this scheme you can't assign a value to the curl at $\vec{u_9}$. Other difference schemes are possible.